# sql insert with null value works on localhost not on live

Tags: mysql, null

```
INSERT INTO `package`(`cid`,`oid`,`toid`,`cat`,`allday`) values( '3' ,'' ,'5','6','Yes');
```

When i run this query it works fine on my localhost but on live server it shows error because there is no value specified for 'oid', My live mysql version is Server version: 5.6.30-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Here is my structure for oid field:
 `oid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,

```
Error i get on live - Field 'oid' is not a integer value
```

Comment: that structure for oid is local or remote?

Comment: That query works on local but not on live.

Answer (score 1):

As the column can't be null and is an tinyint it will try to cast the empty value to an integer. As no integer is given it will give the error you are getting.

There are two options

1. Change the **tinyint(4) not null** to **tinyint(4)** and give a null value:

   INSERT INTO `package`(`cid`,`oid`,`toid`,`cat`,`allday`) values( '3' ,null ,'5','6','Yes');
2. insert an integer value

   INSERT INTO `package`(`cid`,`oid`,`toid`,`cat`,`allday`) values( '3' ,'0' ,'5','6','Yes');

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but `oid` is `tinyint(4) NOT NULL` and you are storing blank value in `oid` in query. Please allow null value for `oid` column and try below query

```
INSERT INTO `package`(`cid`,`oid`,`toid`,`cat`,`allday`) values( '3' ,null ,'5','6','Yes');
                                                                      ^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the solution for it. 
It was sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES that was not allowing to add null values.

Just set it to sql_mode="" and it worked.

Cheers.